# Why do I need internet to listen to my music library?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I was taking a walk yesterday, and I was listening to music in my personal library. No Apple Music subscription. After awhile, my music stopped. I checked, and it said something about needing internet to access music and turning on cellular music in settings or something like that. It happened again today at the mall.  I'm confused... I thought that my personal library was on my device. Is it? By the way, I am using an iPod touch 6th generation and running (gulp) iOS 9 public beta. My best guess is it's the beta. Maybe they don't want all my music on my device in case I have to reset it. But wouldn't it be backed up to iTunes?

Comment: Tell me what you see here: If you go to the Music app -> My Music and then click on the header above the song list (to switch between Songs, Albums, etc) - the value for "Show Music Available Offline" is it Green for on or white for off? If white, that means it will also show music available via iCloud, and that could be causing the connection problem.

Comment: @smoosher I can't find the header of which you speak - Is there a title on it?

Comment: I will attach it as an answer so you can see the photo but please do not accept it as an answer - if it solves your problem, I'll reword it later.

Comment: @smoosher Hmmm... It says "Show iTunes purchases" on mine... and it's on.

Comment: could you please attach a screenshot of what you see to your question?

Comment: @smoosher Here you go. Maybe we should move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26369/discussion-between-smoooosher-and-oboy).

Comment: Agree entirely the old iPod I had for years worked so much better and easier to use!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yipee! I figured it out! My problem is, as I forgot to mention in the question, I just got a new iPod. Aaaaaaand, I never realized it, but apparently when you get a new device, you have to download all your music into your library. Otherwise, you can still listen to it, but only over internet. Probably to save space. Downloading your songs can be done by tapping on the song or album, and then tapping "Make available offline".

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem which happened after moving to ITunes 12 4 3 and Windows 10 by restoring the iPod to factory settings and then reloading the library.
I can't say I like the new ITunes programme. It certainly is inferior to what went before.